# Question on subtraction of intercepts from a linear regression

Tags: regression

I have a simple theoretical question. Assume that we have a variable $Y_1$ and another variable $Y_2$. We regress $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ on the same independent variables $X$, thus we get two intercepts $\hat{a}_1$ and $\hat{a}_2$.

Let's say I calculate the sum of $\hat{a}_1$ and $\hat{a}_2$. Is this mathematically the same as calculating the sum of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ first, and then regressing this sum on the independent variables $X$, to receive a new intercept? Also the other way around, if I subtract $a_1$ from $a_2$, that should be the same as regressing the difference of $Y_1$  and $Y_2$ on $X$ and looking at the intercept? Intuitively this should apply.

Comment: Do you mean a multivariate regression with a two-dimensional response variable $Y=(Y_1,Y_2)^T$ that depends on the variable $X$?

Comment: I suspect OP means to do two separate regressions.

Comment: sorry, I meant two separate regressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let’s do a simulation in R.

```
set.seed(2019)
N <- 100
X <- rnorm(N)
err1 <- rnorm(N)
err2 <- rnorm(N)
Y1 <- 2*X + err1
Y2 <- -5*X + err2
Y <- Y1 + Y2
L1 <- lm(Y1~X)
L2 <- lm(Y2~X)
L <- lm(Y~X)
summary(L1)
summary(L2)
summary(L)
summary(L1)$coefficients[1,1] + summary(L2)$coefficients[1,1] - summary(L)$coefficients[1,1]
```

Do the intercept terms from L1 and L2 add up to the intercept term in L? If the statement is false, this R code should give a counterexample. This simulation can’t prove the claim, but if the intercepts in L1 and L2 add up to the intercept in L, then it would suggest that you try to prove the claim. You can tweak this code to address the subtraction variant.

**MAJOR EDIT***

Let's do a simulation with nonzero intercepts.

```
set.seed(2019)
N <- 100
X <- rnorm(N)
err1 <- rnorm(N)
err2 <- rnorm(N)
Y1 <- 6 + 2*X + err1
Y2 <- 4 - 5*X + err2
Y <- Y1 + Y2
L1 <- lm(Y1~X)
L2 <- lm(Y2~X)
L <- lm(Y~X)
summary(L1)
summary(L2)
summary(L)
summary(L1)$coefficients[1,1] + summary(L2)$coefficients[1,1]
summary(L)$coefficients[1,1]
```

Now let's do a simulation where the $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ error terms are not independent.

```
library(MASS)
set.seed(2019)
N <- 100
X <- rnorm(N)
err <- mvrnorm(N,c(0,0),matrix(c(1,-0.8,-0.8,1),2,2))
Y1 <- 4 + 2*X + err[,1]
Y2 <- 2 + 5*X + err[,2]
Y <- Y1 + Y2
L1 <- lm(Y1~X)
L2 <- lm(Y2~X)
L <- lm(Y~X)
summary(L1)
summary(L2)
summary(L)
summary(L1)$coefficients[1,1] + summary(L2)$coefficients[1,1]
summary(L)$coefficients[1,1]
```

This one also passes! Finally, let's try nonlinear dependence between $Y_1$ and $Y_2$.

```
set.seed(2019)
N <- 100
X <- rnorm(N)
err1 <- rnorm(N)
err2 <- rnorm(N)
Y1 <- 1 + 2*X + err1
Y2 <- -2 + Y1^2 + err2
Y <- Y1 + Y2
L1 <- lm(Y1~X)
L2 <- lm(Y2~X)
L <- lm(Y~X)
summary(L1)
summary(L2)
summary(L)
summary(L1)$coefficients[1,1] + summary(L2)$coefficients[1,1]
summary(L)$coefficients[1,1]
```

This checks out, too!

Now can you prove the claim in general?

Comment: That shows that my intuition was correct. I can try to prove it now, thanks.

Comment: @Talik3233 If you get the proof, please post it. For others who run the code, note that, while that difference at the end is not zero, -3.885781e-16 is basically zero. The difference is due to numerical approximations by the computer.

Comment: @Talik3233 I’ve just realized that neither the $Y_1$ nor the $Y_2$ regression has an intercept term. That’s a pretty big omission on my part. I am going to run a few more simulations today and post my results.

Comment: thanks. But what you mean by no intercept? If you look at `summary` it says there is an intercept

Comment: @Talik3233 I mean that both regressions have intercepts of zero. When I put nonzero intercepts, the result stays the same: the sum of the L1 and L2 intercepts is the same as the L intercept.

Comment: ah sure, I see it in your code. Thanks for the clarification.